# Package installs fine as dependency from NPM registry but not from GitHub URL?

Tags: node.js, github, babeljs, package.json, truffle

**PREFACE**:  The repository I forked from *does* install fine via NPM when I install it as a package from the NPM registry.  My current guess at this time there is some variance between how directories are set when a package is installed from a registry, as opposed to being installed directly from a GitHub URL in the *package.json* file, and this is causing the *require()* statement that tries to find the *babel-register* module to fail during the *prepack* script execution.  **If someone can point me to a document that clearly explains the steps NPM takes when installing a package from the NPM registry, it might help me figure this out.**

I have a GitHub repo that I forked:

```
 https://github.com/roschler/zos-cli
```

I am trying to install the package as a dependency in my Node.JS package using what I think is the proper format for referencing a GitHub repo and branch, as shown below in my *package.json* file:

```
{
    "name": "basil",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
      "build": "webpack --mode production"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
      "openzeppelin-zos": "^1.9.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "ajv": "^6.5.1",
      "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
      "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
      "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
      "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
      "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
      "webpack": "^4.12.0",
      "webpack-cli": "^3.0.3",
      "zos": "roschler/zos-cli.git#development"
    }
}
```

However, when I execute **npm install** after making that change, I get the following error output:

```
$  npm install

> zos@1.0.0 prepack /home/robert/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-d4bae66a
> truffle compile && rm -rf lib && babel src --out-dir lib

Error: Cannot find module 'babel-register'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:594:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/robert/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-d4bae66a/truffle.js:1:63)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
```

I double-checked and the necessary *babel* elements are in the *node_modules* sub-directory of my project:

```
$ find . -regex .*?babel-register
./node_modules/babel-register
```

I then tried installing the Babel command line version globally and if you look at my *package.json* file I tried installing the Node API version into my project, as per their docs:

```
https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/10/31/setting-up-babel-6

$ npm install --global babel-cli
$ npm install --save-dev babel-core
```

And I still get the exact same error output.  Why is it still complaining about being unable to find **babel-register** and how can I fix this?

**UPDATE**: I tried a full global install like the following and I *still* have the exact same error:

```
npm install -g ajv
npm install -g webpack
npm install -g webpack-cli
npm install -g babel-loader babel-core babel-preset-env babel-preset-react babel-register

# Created a .babelrc file in my project directory with this content:
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "node": "8.9"
      }
    }],
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

**UPDATE 2**: Found this page on Babel register:

```
https://new.babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-register.html
```

Tried the suggested npm install:

```
npm install @babel/core @babel/register --save-dev
```

Still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is zos-cli has a `prepack` script that needs the package's devDependencies to be installed. `prepack` gets run when installing a git dependency (https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts), however the devDependencies only get installed when a package is the root package (https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#devdependencies). So you're effectively trying to build zos-cli without the build tools.

Simply put, installing this module as-is as a git dependency won't work.

Some possible solutions:

1. (preferred) Actually publish the module and use that (you can fork and publish under your own NPM namespace, license permitting)
2. Fork the project on github and setup a branch in which you have already run `npm i; npm run prepack;` and then removed `prepack` from the package.json.

Comment: There's still some strange things going on.  I executed option #2, edited .gitignore so that the node_modules and lib dirs would get pushed, while removing the prepack script.  But during the subsequent npm install I got a strange error indicating babel-register is still unhappy.  Note this invalid path: '/home/robert/Documents/GitHub/ME/zeppelin-os-work/basil.babel-register-error/node_modules/zos/lib/bin/zos-cli.js' that caused the install to fail (ENOENT).  Given that the registry version works, what else does NPM do differently with a registry install that still needs to be done?

Comment: I dug a bit further and actually zos-cli is trying to use babel-register at runtime (see the require in `truffle.js`, which may be dynamically loaded via `src/models/truffle/Truffle.js`). This is generally discouraged in production, but the easy fix would be to move babel-register from devDependencies to normal dependencies (it's being used at runtime, so it isn't strictly a "dev"/build dependency). (Also, as an aside, you don't need to and really shouldn't include the node_modules in the repo. The important bit was to get the build step done, not have the dependencies there.).

Comment: As a PoC, I get no errors when installing with this as the git reference for zos: `gpittarelli/zos-cli.git#gjp-built`

Comment: With your last comment, are you saying you were able to install it with your fork being an unmodified copy of the source repo, or after you made the changes you recommend in the comment immediately above this one, where you talk about babel-register being used at runtime by zos-cli?  Also, did you make your fork from the Open Zeppelin's original repo, which I made mine from, or did you fork from my fork of that repo?

Comment: Please ignore my last comment. I was really tired when I wrote it.  I'm looking at your repo and branch now.  I will try out your changes later today.  Still, you have to admit that it's strange that installing it from the registry works without modification.  There's something NPM must be doing differently when installing from the registry, that changes the execution environment from that which occurs when installing from a GitHub URL.

Comment: Just accepted your answer.  Now that I know what is going on, thanks to your reply, I just installed zos-cli as a package from my local clone of my zos-cli fork.  Don't even have to pull from GitHub.  Thanks.  Some day I'll go to the trouble of cloning the NPM repo and trace the code, just to find out why packages pulled from the NPM registry install differently than those that install from a GitHub URL, but not today.

Comment: The difference is that `prepack` doesn't run when installing from the registry (because the code is expected to already be fully built before being packed and published to  the registry)

Comment: And there it is.  I've never published a GitHub repo to the NPM registry.  So I take it from what you just said a package developer does the exact steps you suggested to fully form the package are done by an NPM package author before publishing.  Thanks again.  Amazing how one piece of knowledge like that can cost someone a lot of time.